# How to animate graph of data in python using matplotlib.animation

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I have two arrays x and y, each one has more than 365000 elements. I would like to draw an animated line using these array elements. I'm using matplotlib.animation for it. Problem is when I execute the code below I can't see the graph smoothly(animated) drawed. Contrary I see it's final drawed version.

[image: This is what I obtain]

Here is my code:

```
#libs
# Movement instance creation-----------------------------
movement1=Movement(train1, track1)
# # Move the train on the track

movement1.move()
y = movement1.speed
x = movement1.pos

Writer = animation.writers['ffmpeg']
writer = Writer(fps=20, metadata=dict(artist='Me'), bitrate=1800)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 25), ylim=(0, 300))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)
# initialization function: plot the background of each frame
def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

# animation function.  This is called sequentially
def animate(i):
    line.set_data(x, y)
    return line,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                                frames=200, interval=200, blit=True)


anim.save('basic_animation.mp4', writer=writer)
```

Here is the similar result that I expect:

[image: Here is the similar result that I expect.]

Of course my graph would be another curve.

Comment: What's in `x` and `y`?

Comment: they are arrays like
    x=[0.0004663, 0.0004667, ... 25]
    y=[0.0002235, 0.0002354, ... 300]

Comment: And those are the points you want to plot?

Comment: yes, but plot them in an animated way. I mean draw an animated curve using elements of these arrays. I found [How to Create Animated Graphs in Python](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-create-animated-graphs-in-python-bb619cc2dec1) by Viviane. After I changed those codes my computer just starts to hang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is mostly fine; you just need to do three things.

1. Set the `xdata` and `ydata` of the line to different values every iteration of `anim_func` (otherwise, there would be no animation, would there?)
2. Set constant axis limits so your plot doesn't change shape
3. Remove the `save` call for display purposes (for me personally, I find it affects the animation)

So:

```
ax.axis((x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max())

def animate(i):
    line.set_data(x[:i], y[:i])
    return line,
```

Comment: how I can send this file (basic_animation.mp4) to my html template?

Comment: @FarkhadL. that would probably be the subject of a separate question.

Comment: I have already created the question, I've written to you since I have no response there))) 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55451072/how-to-pass-animation-video-file-created-by-matplotlib-to-template-file-in-fla

Comment: @FarkhadL. I would like to help you, but...I don't know much about Flask. Sorry!

Comment: Thank you for concerning

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a set of data that is changing for animation to occur. In the example site you gave, the author does it by slicing the data using overdose.iloc[:int(i+1] (see below for the actual code used). This is the part that creates the animation as matplotlib plots whatever data is in the animate function. In your code you have input line.set_data(x, y) which I suppose is your entire dataset. That's why it isn't moving.

```
def animate(i):
    data = overdose.iloc[:int(i+1)] #select data range
    p = sns.lineplot(x=data.index, y=data[title], data=data, color="r")
    p.tick_params(labelsize=17)
    plt.setp(p.lines,linewidth=7)
```

Second thing to note is that your plot is getting chopped off at the top. That is likely because your initialisation is already setting the axis wrongly. What I would do is to add in a plt.axis([0, 25, 0, 'upper limit']) to help set the axis correctly.

Comment: `tps = pd.DataFrame(y,x)`
`Writer = animation.writers['ffmpeg']`
`writer = Writer(fps=20, metadata=dict(artist='Me'), bitrate=1800)`
`def animate(i):`
    `data = tps.iloc[:int(30000*i+1)] #select data range
    p = sns.lineplot(x=data.index, y=data[0], data=data, color="r")
    p.tick_params(labelsize=17)
    plt.setp(p.lines,linewidth=7)
    ani = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=13, 
    repeat=False)
    ani.save('TPS.mp4', writer=writer)`