# How to pass animation video file (created by matplotlib) to template file in Flask

Tags: python, matplotlib, flask

I am trying to display animated video file generated by `matplotlib.animation` in template html file. After following code below I recieve: `flask.cli.NoAppException: While importing "plot", an ImportError was raised:`

Here is the code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, send_file

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
import io
import base64
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from StringIO import StringIO
@app.route('/anim')
def build_animated():
    *****
    # Movement instance creation-----------------------------
    movement1=Movement(train1, track1)
    # Move the train on the track
    movement1.move()
    y = movement1.speed
    x = movement1.pos


    Writer = animation.writers['ffmpeg']
    writer = Writer(fps=15, metadata=dict(artist='Me'), bitrate=1800)

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 35), ylim=(0, 350))
    line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)
    # initialization function: plot the background of each frame
    def init():
        line.set_data([], [])
        return line,

    # animation function.  This is called sequentially
    def animate(i):
        # y = movement1.speed
        # x = movement1.pos
        line.set_data(x[:i*25000], y[:i*25000])
        return line,

    anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                                    frames=20, interval=36, blit=True)
    anim.save('basic_animation.mp4', writer=writer)
    img = StringIO()
    fig.savefig(img)
    img.seek(0)
    return send_file(img, mimetype='image/png')
```

I expect the video file to be displayed in my html file in template folder

Comment: We'll need a little more information here to know what's going on, since you imply the error occurs on an `import` statement, but you don't have any on your code.

Comment: I would like that basic_animation.mp4 to be displayed in my html file. I mean how one can send the video file to a view

Comment: You would need to send the file you saved, not a single frame buffer. Possibly you can also save the animation to a buffer instead.

Comment: could you please give a piece of code or reference how to do that?
thank you